# ngCookies doesnt work properly after i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Im using angularjs in my project , and when the client log in , than a service save his information in the cookies .

by using this code:

```
$cookies.put('username',$rootScope.username);
```

or

```
$cookies.username = $rootScope.username;
```

i try them both.

in the first try , i tried : `console.log($cookies.get('username');` and it doesnt work at all.

but in the second try when i tried : `console.log($cookies.username);` it did print the information.

but after i refreshed the page , this `$cookies.username;` didnt work anymore..

what maybe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To access the cookie you need to do `$cookies.get('username')`

It seems in your first console.log there is a typo, you're missing the last parenthesis

Try this

```
console.log($cookies.get('username'));
```

Also, make sure your $rootScope.username attribute has a value in it